# How to get the value of advanced power settings

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, uwp, uwp-xaml, xamarin.uwp

I try to read/get those advanced settings values such as *Put the computer to sleep* on my UWP application and follow this article [How to get the value of advanced power settings](http://www.reza-aghaei.com/how-to-get-value-of-advanced-power-settings/) but in UWP it is not working because the example is only for Windows 8.1 and WPF.

Anybody have tried this kind of features in their application?

My goal only for this is to get the values from the corresponding settings.

[image: POWER AND SLEEP SETTINGS]

Comment: You can have a look at Windows.System.Power [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.power).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's easily achievable. There's no out of the box API exposed to retrieve such data. Not according to to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/) at least.

I'm pretty sure you would need to deal with the [native interoperability](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/native-interop) (aka `DllImport`). Check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16025694/510627) on how to retrieve this kind of data and use it as a guideline to retrieve data that you're interested in